# Function is partial differentiable but has no total derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have to give an example of a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that has partial derivatives $(\partial_1f)(0,0) = 1 = (\partial_2f)(0,0)$ but no total derivative in $(0,0)$.

I think that the function 
$$
  f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R},
  \quad 
  f(x,y) =
  \begin{cases}
  \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} + x + y & \text{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$} \\
  0 & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$} 
  \end{cases}
$$
is an example, I'm just not sure if my proof is correct.

We know that $f$ is total differentiable if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ because the partial derivatives exist and are continuous.

$f$ is also partial differentiable if $(x,y) = (0,0)$ because $f(x,0) = x$ and $f(0,y) = y$ and they are given by $(\partial_1 f)(x,0) = 1 = (\partial_2f)(0,y) = 1$.

To proof that $f$ is total differentiable in $(0,0)$ we now only have to proof that 
$$
    f(x,y)
  = (1,1)
    \begin{pmatrix}
      x \\
      y \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    + o(\| (x,y) \|)
  \qquad
  \text{when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$}
$$
but this doesn't hold when $x=y=t$ and $t \to 0$ and so $f$ is not total differentiable when $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Can someone confirm if this is correct?

Comment: For me, it's correct.

Comment: I found no error.

Comment: Is the function weakly differentiable? Is $f\in W^{1,1}([0,1]^2)$? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have it right.

Your function has partial derivatives at the origin without being continuous.